# Function to stop a setInterval call leaving the width style static

Tags: javascript, function, css, setinterval

The code below (found here) shows a kind of progress bar that moves very fast towards the right side re-starting non stop. This is done by changing the element's width within a setInterval.

How can I build a function that freezes the progress bar motion when called (stops the width from changing freezing it in the moment the function is called)?

I'm working with prototype/javascript (the jQuery line in the code is a fast way to add a class in order to publish this post, but I'm not using jQuery).

```
   <style>

    .thepower {
      opacity: 0;
        background-color: #191919;
      padding: 4px;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 300px;
      height: 24px;
      top:150px;
      left:84px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
      border-radius: 16px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #000, 0 1px 0 #2b2b2b;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #000, 0 1px 0 #2b2b2b;
    }

    .visible.thepower {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .thepower .inner {  
      background: #999;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-width: 97.5% !important; 
      height: 24px;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),
        inset 0 -1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
        0 1px 1px #000;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 
       inset 0 -1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 
       0 1px 1px #000;

    }

    .green .inner { 
      background: #7EBD01;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#7EBD01), to(#568201));

    }

    </style>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // How it works:
/*
    var counter = 0 (inside a function, window.onload) - A local variable is defined and initialised at zero.
    window.setInterval(function(){ ... }, 50) - An interval is defined, activating the function (first argument) every 50 milliseconds (20x a second, adjust to your own wishes)
    (++counter % 101) - Increments the counter by one, modulo 101:
    The modulo operator calculates the remainder after division, ie: 0 % 101 = 0, 100 % 101 = 100 and 200 % 101 = 99, 201 % 101 = 100, 202 % 101 = 100
    */



    window.onload = function(){   

        var counter = 0;
        window.setInterval(function(){
              $(".green").addClass("visible")   ;
           document.querySelector('.green.thepower.visible .inner').style.width =    (++counter % 101) + '%';                                          

        }, 10);


    }
    </script>


    <div id="thepower" ad-outlet="thepower">
    <div class="green thepower"><div  class="inner"></div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to stop and continue from where you left off:

Add this to your HTML:

```
<button id="toggleProgress">Click</button>
```

and change your javascript to this:

```
var counter = 0;
var timer = null;
function progressBar(){
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = null;
        return;
    }
    timer = window.setInterval(function(){
        $(".green").addClass("visible");
        document.querySelector('.green.thepower.visible .inner').style.width = (++counter % 101) + '%';
    }, 10);
}

window.onload = function() {
    progressBar();
    $('#toggleProgress').click(function() {
        progressBar();
    });
};
```

Comment: this is almost it! I just have to make the button be a one click one, meaning one click the action stops, a second or more clicks and nothing happens, it stays where the first click left it. I'll let you know if I can get it. Thanks!

Comment: If you were using jQuery, you'd just have to replace .click() with .one('click', ...). Otherwise, you can remove the event listener within the handler, or just store an outside flag (eg. var clicked = false) and check for it in the handler. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clearInterval` method to stop executing of the method which was set with `setInterval`. First save the result of `setInterval` to some variable:

```
var interval;

window.onload = function(){   
    var counter = 0;

    interval = window.setInterval(function(){
        $(".green").addClass("visible")   ;
        document.querySelector('.green.thepower.visible .inner').style.width =    (++counter % 101) + '%';                                          
    }, 10);
}
```

After that call clearInterval somewhere passing saved value as parameter:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```